# Why a get "Webdriver executable need to be in path" when I try to implement my function inside a loop

Tags: python, selenium

I have an issue with my selenium script. when I put my bot function inside a loop. I get this error in the second iteration. "Webdriver executable need to be in path".

## this a example of the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    schedule.every(1).minute.do(applying_bot, target_page)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It literally tells you what the problem is.  Your webdriver executable needs to be in path

Comment: But, when I run the script without loop, it work. this my bot object:

Comment: but when i run the script once it work, but when I wrap it in the schedule module it's fire me this error in the second iteration